# Android Nexus 7 tablet emulator not load correct layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm writing an app that should support both phones and tablets.

I created `layout-sw600dp layout-large` folders under `res`, and also added `support-screens` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it seems that the emulator always loads the layout file `activity_main.xml` under `layout` folder.

```
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

I also found some related topics, but didn't get an answer there.

[Android Emulator loading wrong layout screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128305/android-emulator-loading-wrong-layout-screen-sizes)

[Why does Android's Nexus 7 virtual device not load my "large" layout resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786506/why-does-androids-nexus-7-virtual-device-not-load-my-large-layout-resources)

[Android stretches the layout file instead of loading the correct file in the res folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277330/android-stretches-the-layout-file-instead-of-loading-the-correct-file-in-the-res)

Is the issue with emulator or anything else I need to fix?

Answer (score 15):

I experienced pretty much the same thing while developing my first app for tablets. I would suggest that you edit your Tablet emulator preferences in ADV Manager and set the "Custom Skin Definition" to "none" under the Advanced Settings menu.